# How can I use C# Excel "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel", to count the amount of not empty cells in a one columns

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

So I have this spreadsheet, it has Fname, Lname, Pnumber, Email, Cid. Cid is the only really important one, the rest are optional technically.

So instead of just doing a loop to see when the cell values starts being null, I know you can use the

WorksheetFunction.CountA(some 30 different variable that I do not understand but are optional too);

to get the actual numbers of filled cells, and it is instant. I have no idea how to do this.

This is what I'm going to do viva looping, but I know the CountA() function can do it in one line.

```
int i = 1;
while (i <= 200)
{
    cell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[i, 5];
    if (cell.Value2 > 0)
    {i++;}
    else
    {break;}
}
int totalCol = i;
```

---

Ok, this is what I have now, thanks everyone.

```
var cell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
    cell.Formula = "=CountA(E1:E200)";
                    double totalCells = (cell.Value2) -1;
```

Comment: range.Value2 gives you an object array of the items in the Range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not in the IDE right now, but this should do the trick:

```
    Dim cl As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
    cl.Formula = "=CountA(E1:E200)"
    myVal = cl.Value
```

Comment: This is in c#, I probably should have specify that. Sorry, I'm not used to the Excel library.

Comment: Ok, I got it working, thanks. I keep missing that it wants everything to stay as a double, and I keep using integers.

Comment: var cell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
cell.Formula = "=CountA(E1:E200)";
                double totalCells = (cell.Value2) -1;